# Bootstrap: Scale image to other parent content, and switch between inline and block displays based on content size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

I've tried several different approaches, and keep getting minor issues with getting an image to display next to text in Bootstrap (with some resizing requirements).

Specific requirements:

- The clock icon should scale to the height of the text to its right
- The red box should only use as much space as it requires - thus it should be inline if it fits in next to the phrase 'Other Content', and a block underneath it only if it doesn't fit in.

[Required view on a narrow screen (approximate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0P6l.png)

[Required view on a wide screen (approximate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSt2.png)

How could one get this done?

**MWE:**

HTML snippet

```
Other content
<div class="sars-notice row">
    <img src="images/infored.png" alt="Info Notice" class="col-sm-1">
    <span class="col-sm-11">Single or multiple lines, depending on content</span>
</div>
```

CSS snippet (not shown is bootstrap4's minimum css library):

```
.sars-notice {
    min-height: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid darkred;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    background-color: pink;
    color: darkred;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codpen.io](https://codpen.io) of what did you try for us.

Answer (score 0):

As bootstrap is a mobile-first approach library, you can have it so in mobile view there are going to be 2 cols that thakes all the width (`col-12`) and from small screens onwards (`col-sm-x`) the layout is going to be 11-1.

```
Other content
<div class="sars-notice row">
    <img src="images/infored.png" alt="Info Notice" class="col-12 col-sm-1>
    <span class="col-12 col-sm-11">Single or multiple lines, depending on content</span>
</div>
```